# How to set up another action after a button click

Tags: java, android, android-button

I'm trying to set up a a button that writes morse code in a form of a string. The button should work similar to early morse code machines. If you tap it, it inserts a dot, if you hold it for longer(onLongClick setting is 500ms i think) it inserts a dash and if it hasnt been pressed for a while, it assumes that you have input a morse letter/symbol. The latter part is something i can't really figure out how to implement.

Currently i'm trying to set two listeners. One that uses onClick(), the other one uses onLongClick(). Then they call methods which build on my morse string while outputting the built string in textView. After a button is pressed, i have a delay timer which after a second should check if the button is pressed and if it is not pressed, it should add a / to the morse string signifying that the letter has been successfully written. Here is my code(ignore the onLongClick listener and the addWordSpace method cause those are not implemented yet). The issue is that when i emulate my app and after i click the button once to insert a dot, even tho i don't do anything for a second, it doesn't insert a / symbol using the addLetterSpace method.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public Button buttonIn;
public TextView textOut;
public String morse;
private static boolean run = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonIn = findViewById(R.id.buttonIn);
    textOut = findViewById(R.id.textOut);
    morse = "";


    buttonIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View activity_main){

            setDot();

            final Timer delayTimer = new Timer();
            final TimerTask delayTask = new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (run) {
                        if(!buttonIn.isPressed()){
                            addLetterSpace();
                            textOut.setText(morse);
                        }
                    } else {
                        delayTimer.cancel();
                        delayTimer.purge();
                    }
                }
            };
            delayTimer.schedule(delayTask, 1000);
            run = false;
            textOut.setText(morse);

        }
    } );
//IGNORE THIS LISTENER.
    buttonIn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
        public boolean onLongClick(View activity_main){
            setDash();
            Timer delayTimer = new Timer();
            delayTimer.schedule(
                new TimerTask(){
                    public void run(){
                    while(!buttonIn.isPressed()){
                        addLetterSpace();
                        textOut.setText(morse);
                        break;
                        }
                    }
                },
            1000);
            delayTimer.cancel();
        return true;
        }
    });

}

public String setDot(){

    morse = morse + ".";

    return morse;
}
public String setDash(){
    morse = morse + "-";
    return morse;
}
public String addLetterSpace(){
    morse = morse + "/";
    return morse;
}
public String addWordSpace(){
    morse = morse + "%";
    return morse;
}
}
```

Comment: Use a single, common timer, defined outside the listeners. Simply reset it in `onClick` and `onLongClick`. Start it on the first occurence of either event. `isPressed` can't really help you here.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Thanks. Using a single, common timer makes more sense than what i tried. Also it sucks that isPressed won't help me. I guess my approach on designing this is completely wrong.

Comment: I wonder if there is a way of measuring idle time and using that to trigger the completion of letters and sentences while building the morse string using the button.